# Selenium Chrome Driver In Tomcat is not working why?

Tags: java, selenium, tomcat, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

was trying run my selenium automation code using java in a Tomcat server. It works fine when I run using javac but when it gets run on Tomcat as a jar It shows "`com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V|`" this as a log. Here my selenium-chrome driver is placed in desktop of my local machine and path is defined (Tomcat is also a local server)

Comment: It doesn't really matter which way you do it. In all approaches you're going to read the file line by line.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a buffered file reader like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        File f = new File("data.txt");
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String readLine;
        while ((readLine = b.readLine()) != null) {
        if (readLine.contains("WORD"))
            System.out.println("Found WORD in: " + readLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

where "WORD" is the word you are searching for.

The advantage of a `BufferedReader` is that it reads ahead to reduce the number of I/O roundtrips - or as they put it in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html): "Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines."

`FileChannel` is a slightly newer invention, arriving in the NIO with Java 1.4. It might perform better than the BufferedReader - but I also find it a lot more low-level in its API, so unless you have very special performance requirements, I would leave the readahead/buffering to `BufferedReader` and `FileReader`.

You can also say that `BufferedReader` is "line oriented" whereas `FileChannel` is "byte oriented".

Comment: Why was this answer "unaccepted" without a comment?

Comment: because the question was edited into a request for good reviews for his website. I've rolled it back (but that didn't help your accept)

Answer (score 0):

I like the BufferedReader from Java.io with a FileReader most:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html
- https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

It is easy to use and has most functions. But your file mus be char-based to use that ( like a text file)